# Download file from the shared folder of Google Drive by using rclone

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, rclone

I'm wondering if rclone is able to donwload file from the shared folder of Google Drive. If yes, what is the command to do it?

```
rclone sync cloud_name:(what is the shared folder name?)file_name destination_path
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `rclone config` to create a `remote:` for the Google 'Shared Drive'. See https://rclone.org/drive/

The line `Configure this as a Shared Drive (Team Drive)?`

Then the sync would be:

`rclone sync SharedDriveName:"Directory/Directory" YourOtherRemote:"Directory/Directory"`

Useful flags are:

`-P` or `--progress` (see progress during transfer)

`-vv` (see detailed logs)

`--create-empty-src-dirs` (to recreate empty directories)

`-u` or `--update` (Skip files that are newer on the destination)

`--drive-server-side-across-configs` (if you want to sync native Google docs)

`--dry-run` (as a practise)